# Why enabling torch mode is slow on the first time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I am trying to implement a torch feature in my app using AVFoundation, but the problem is when i switched it on for the first time, it's slow. Should i initiate something on viewDidLoad to not get this problem?

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if ([device hasTorch]) {
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:(sender.isOn)?AVCaptureTorchModeOn:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: Because tar takes time to set on fire and fire to heat up...

Comment: @H2CO3 ... lol , you are on fire today !

Comment: But when i look into the other torch app, There's no such thing?